# SlideUp DIV of same class before SlideDown Jquery

Tags: jquery, slide, slidedown, slideup

I'm sure the answer is simple but;
I'm trying to write a simple bit of Jquery for a restaurant menu system on a website.
I want the menu_list item to that is visible to slideUp before the selected one slidesDown I can get this to work by delaying the slideDown, this is great if a menu_list is already visible but means you get a delay if one is not.
I've tried deferring but for some reason the second menu_list just appears bellow the current one instead of the current one sliding up first.
I've tried if else but that doesn't work either.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

This code works but is delayed (for obvious reasons)

```
$('.s_menu, .m_menu').click(function(){
var menuid = event.target.id;
var mlist = ('#') + (menuid) + ('_list');
var last = $('.menu_list').not(mlist);

    $(last).slideUp(400);
    $(mlist).delay(600).slideDown(400);

    return(false);
  });
});
```

This code the divs appear below each other without the previous sliding up.

```
function first(){$(last).slideUp(400);}
function next(){$(mlist).slideDown(400);}

$.when(first).then(next);
    return(false);
  });
});
```

as does this

```
  if ($(last).is(':hidden')) {
    $(mlist).slideDown(400);
  } else {      
    $(last).slideUp(400);
    $(mlist).delay(600).slideDown(400);
  }
    return(false);
   });
});
```

HMTL is:

```
<div id="menu_nav">

                <ul class="menu_top">
                    <li id="menu_starters" class="menu">STARTERS</li>
                    <li id="menu_mains" class="menu" >MAINS</li>
                    <li id="menu_noodles" class="menu">NOODLES &amp RICE</li>
                </ul>   

                <ul id="start_nav" class="menu_sub">
                    <li id="st_meat" class="s_menu">MEAT &amp FISH</li>
                    <li id="st_veg" class="s_menu">VEGETARIAN</li>
                    <li id="st_soups" class="s_menu">SOUPS</li>
                    <li id="st_salads" class="s_menu">SALADS</li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="mains_nav" class="menu_sub">
                    <li id="ma_curries" class="m_menu">CURRIES</li>
                    <li id="ma_meat" class="m_menu">MEAT</li>
                    <li id="ma_seafood" class="m_menu">SEAFOOD</li>
                    <li id="ma_veg" class="m_menu">VEGETARIAN</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
<article id="st_meat_list" class="st menu_list">
<ul>
<!--series of list items here-->
</ul>
 <article id="st_veg_list" class="st menu_list">
<ul>
<!--series of list items here-->
</ul>
 <article id="st_soups_list" class="st menu_list">
<ul>
<!--series of list items here-->
</ul>
```

and so on with articles containing each list

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4K6be/3/)

Comment: What does your html look like? Also, I'm not clear on whether you want the delay to be there or not. Also also, a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be great here.

Comment: sorry I've edited with html I hope that helps.

Comment: I've also added a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Since you will only have one submenu sliding down all the time, try hide() all the submenu before sliding down the targeted one, and use the callback of hide() to slide down the targeted menu. Could be something like this:

```
$('.s_menu, .m_menu').click(function(){
  var correspnding_list = $(selector_to_mlist);
  var list = $('.common_class_of_lists');
   list.slideUp({
     complete: function (){
       corresponding_list.slideDown();
     }
   })
});
```

Update: Please use slideToggle() instead of slideDown()

http://jsfiddle.net/XK6JX/

Comment: This seems to just run the functions simultaneously which is not what I want. I want the existing menu to slide up and then the corresponding menu to slide down.

Comment: Somehow slideDown as a callback in slideUp does wait for the slideUp to finish. Using slideToggle() instead will get the effect of what OP wants.

Comment: I'm afraid the slideToggle doesn't give me the effect I want, firstly once more menu items are added it seems to go a bit mad (when I applied it to the working version it would slide up and down about 6 times and then remain up!) [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/JakeLabz/29TyG/). Also it means that when the same menu item is clicked again the list item slides up and down again, and I don't want this.

Comment: yeah, the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method is widely used for dropdown menus to prevent such yoyo effects :)

Comment: And a bit off topic, I am not sure if using so many <article> tags with the same class to work with jquery animation is a good idea. I would rather use only one div and use jquery to print out content from html templates. Too much animation going at the same time is very hard to manage the timing, which is why you are having such problem now.